# Should I store Employee StartDate as DT_Date, DT_DBDate or DateTime2

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a new Employee Tracking app that I am building.  I am importing the employee data from an Excel Spreadsheet using SSIS into MSSQL 2016 Database.   Should I transform and save the employee StartDate info as a 'DT_Date', 'DT_DBDate' or 'DateTime2'?

It seems to me that I should save it as a DT_DBDate type since the time of day at which a person joined is never relevant in my app. I am concerned however, that I might be limiting myself in being able to do things in the future such as datetime arithmetic and have been unable to find anywhere articles on when to use the different date types. I'm hoping to get any suggestions on what type I should choose and why.

Comment: if you dont need time, `DT_DBDate` sound like the right option.

Comment: i think the safest option is datetime.

Comment: Knowing what your vote is, unfortunately doesn't help me.  I need to know why - i.e.  what could happen that would make date less safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience of dealing with Excel source data, when it comes to datetime/date fields treat them as strings and use derived column transformations to modify the data into the data type that you need. You may get into strange issues. If your end column is date then DT_DBDATE or if your end column is a datetime, DT_DBDATETIME.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My main concern is not so much about how to transform the data as much as what the best ultimate datatype to store the StartDate in the MSSQL Server 2016 database.  Should I store it as date or datetime2?  I will never need to know what time of day the employee started but I am concerned that I may run into future limitations if I choose the date field.  Your thoughts appreciated.

Comment: As I have mentioned, it is based on your requirement. If you want to have time component logged, then between datetime and datetime2, go with datetime2 as it gives you larger range and greater flexibility in terms of storage and functions that can be applied. SQL Server 2016 version hasn't added any specific improvements to datetime. Please refer to this article - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/ that gives a very good insight of best practices to follow and common pitfalls with regards to date/datetime.

Comment: Thanks - I will use the date format - your comments and the article you linked to were very helpful